# Can I return built-in pipe?

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-pipe

I have a question about angular2 pipe.
I want to get pipes as return value depending on schema:string.
I think 2 way to get it, but both are not working.

page.html

```
<p>{{value | getSchema(value, schema)}}</p>
```

page.ts

```
getSchema(value, schema){
    if(schema == 'Currency'){
        return "currency: 'USD':true";
    } else if(schema == 'Number'){
        return 'number';
    }
}
```

or

page.html

```
<p>{{getSchema(value, schema)}}</p>
```

page.ts

```
getSchema(value, schema){
    if(schema == 'Currency'){
        return value + "| currency: 'USD':true";
    } else if(schema == 'Number'){
        return value + '| number';
    }
}
```

is there any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Why not put the switch logic inside a pipe that takes arguments instead? It will be clearer and probably not as bad performance wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom pipe that calls to another pipe depending on the parameter

```ts
@Pipe({name: 'genericPipe'})
class MyPipe {
  constructor(private currPipe:CurrencyPipe, private numberPipe:NumberPipe) {}
  transform(value, schema) {
    if(schema == 'Currency') {
      return this.currPipe.transform(value);
    } else {
      return this.numberPipe.transform(value);
    }
  }
}
```

```ts
<p>{{value | genericPipe:schema}}</p>
```